# How to call function from one object literal to other object literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to call function from one object literal to other object literal

```
// File name: file1.js
var common = {
    init: function() {
        this.function1();
    }
    function1: function() {
        // Here, I want to call function2 function from "other" object literal. 
        // How to do that?
    }
}
common.init();

// File name: file2.js
var other = {
    function2: function() {
    }
}
```

Comment: try loading both pages in the same html/php file, and type file2.js before file1.js

Comment: flip the js files sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have anything special to do except :
make sure they are **both** included in the HTML page where you want to use File1 and that File2 is declared **before** File1

Comment: If your problem is solved, accept the answer so that your subject is closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Call `common.init()` after the `other` variable:

```
var common = {
    init: function() {
        this.function1();
    },
    function1: function() {
        other.function2();
    }
};

var other = {
    function2: function() {
        alert('other.function2');
    }
};

common.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just function2 from the 'other' object from inside function1:

```
var common = {
    init: function() {
        this.function1();
    }
    function1: function() {
        other.function2();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have syntax error, the `init` and `function1` should separate by `,` from each other.